# HttpWebResponse gives expired cookie

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm trying to login in to a camera and get json response on a certain webpage. when I do on some cameras its fine. Some cameras the cookies will come back with very old date. any ideas why that would happen.

```
// login in requset
_request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_uri);
_request.KeepAlive = true;
_request.UserAgent = "curl/7.54.1\r\n";
_request.ContentType = "application/json";
_request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
_request.Method = "POST";

using (var sw = new StreamWriter(_request.GetRequestStream()))
{
   string json = jsonCommand;

   sw.Write(json);
   sw.Flush();
   sw.Close();
}

// get cookies
request.CookieContainer = cookie;
request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
var cookies = response.Cookies;

foreach (Cookie cook in cookies)
{
   _cookie.Add(cook);
}

// send a request for a json response
_request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_uri);
_request.KeepAlive = true;
_request.UserAgent = "curl/7.54.1\r\n";
_request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
```

Comment: The cookie is stored in the device and remembers the client IP address.  Unless the expiration data is exceeded the device will use old cookie.

Comment: I'm connecting to a unifi camera. I login through a browser and it shows the authid and expiration date as todays date but when I use the above code in c# it will have old expiration date. does that mean there is a certain way to login through those ones or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Does the camera have the correct date and timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SUCCESS:**

The camera is a unifi uvc g2. I set the date and time and i was able to use the code above to get the json response. the only problem was that I had to connect to manage the camera through the NVR to get the time to sync.

**UNSUCCESS:**
Once I manage and unmanage the camera it will sync long as I don't fiddle with the settings for the date time.